# How to use Customvalidator to check number

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, customvalidator

I was trying to use `Customvalidator` to check value, and make sure that the value should be integer and also it can't be null. At beginning, I use the `RequiredValidator` and `RegularExpressionValidator` to achieve that. However, I could not put their errormessage in the same place, so I change my solution to use Customvalidator. But I still can't figure out it.

Here is my code

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
     DateTime dt;

     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Value))
     {
         CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "Can not be empty";
         args.IsValid = false;
     }

     else if (????)
     {
        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: `However, I could not put their errormessage in the same place,` so placing was the issue when you tried first ?

Comment: yes, it's my first question. Do u know how to place two errormessage together?

Comment: You can use the Tim schmelter solution. It will work perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `int.TryParse` or `decimal.TryParse` to check if the string is a valid number.

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
     args.IsValid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Value);
     if (!args.IsValid)
     {
         CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "Can not be empty";
     }
     else
     {
         int number;
         args.IsValid = int.TryParse(args.Value, out number);
         if(!args.IsValid)
         {
             CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "Must be a valid integer";
         }
     }
}
```

Note that you also have to set [`ValidateEmptyText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.validateemptytext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `true`(default: `false`). It's the only validator  which doesn't need an additional `RequiredFieldValidator`.